# Need to restore emails that Outlook deleted from the mail server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pop3, webmail

I wanted to use POP mail for my Yahoo mail account.

1. So I went to the Yahoo mail settings and enabled POP feature.
2. I installed Microsoft Outlook 2007 and added the settings for my Yahoo mail account.
3. Then I performed a sync.

I successfully received all the emails from Yahoo account into my pc. But when I logged into my Yahoo mail online, to my horror all the mails were deleted. It seems someone in Microsoft for some reason decided to keep the default setting unchecked for "Leave copy of messages on the server". This has been a very old account and I need to have all the mails also present on the mail server so I can access it anytime and future purposes.

**Is there anyway I can restore these emails on the server again? Any ideas how I can get it back to the way it was?** I have been googling this for quite sometime now but I'm not able to find it.

Any helpful suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, come on. Arguing over the technicalities of whether it's the fault of Outlook or POP is completely irrelevant. Please focus on trying to _solve the problem_ - recovering Mugen's emails to his Yahoo account - instead. Off-topic comments have been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better option is to create a new account on outlook using the same yahoo id and using the IMAP settings.

Once the settings are done & sync is complete, you will be able to see the downloaded mails available on the web.

This however has one drawback, it will remove the original time stamp and will show you the time stamp of the day when the outlook was sync with web.

Comment: Okay this option sounds really cool. Will update the thread after I've tried this out later.

Comment: You will NOT be able to see them till you drag/drop/copy/move them back into IMAP Inbox. Further: Dropping from the POP local account to the online IMAP Inbox account (if same Outlook) >WILL NOT< change date stamp. The entire EML should be preserved and thus the timestamp.

Comment: You were off to a good start. Edit your answer and will upvote.

Answer (score 2):

As TFM has pointed out, this is the default setting of POP3. For us old school guys, this is what we expect. Back in the day, keeping emails on your PC **and** your mail server was expensive.  We had rinky dinky 800 **MB** harddrives and even less room on our mail servers.

That was the reality when I first started using POP. And that was what POP was originally designed for.

If all your emails are still in Outlook, there is an easy remedy. Just email all those messages back to yourself, making sure to leave a copy on the server.

This reminds me of the stories on *The Old New Thing*. One of those situations where Microsoft gets blamed whether or not it's actually their fault. They might of did this to stay compliant. But that of course has its consequences. I remember when XP first came out and finally got rid of the accursed DOS kernel.  People riotted!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah I guess I'll forward all emails back to the server. Only problem is the timestamp and the "From" field will be wrong. Could there be another way to restore the emails?

Comment: There is a way, I'm not sure of a **fast** way to do it.  You'll have to hit up some of the Outlook experts on the Microsoft forums.  I think it is called "redirect" or something.  The suck part is I don't know how you would do it for multiple messages with just the GUI.  You'll have to bribe one of the experts to write a VBA macro. for you.

Comment: Forwarding or emailing them does NOT preserve the original date or header.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and also found the solution. I've found all the mails in the Trash folder. I just moved those to Inbox. That's it.

Comment: That sounds great. It wasn't the case during the days I logged this question..

Comment: That's only possible when using IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

1. create another account this time use IMAP.
2. Copy your  mail from the POP account to the IMAP Account and they will sync back online.

Comment: Clearest/best answer. You are copying them to your Inbox I assume though (on the IMAP)